# Logs growing and took up entire log drive even with log backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, transaction-log

I have a volume just for logs and another volume just for log backups.

The log volume kept  growing until it to run out of space even with log backups taken every 1 minute.

Isn't the backups suppose to free up the space within the log file to be written over again?

It seems like this isn't happening.

Comment: Do you have any very long running transactions? SQL Server won't clear out vlfs from the transaction logs until they aren't in use.

Comment: I have a very large restore job that query is being ran off another serve to a full backup from the server in question but that should affect it I wouldn't assume. I'll have to verify there are no rogue SQL jobs. The volume was 600gb which for a quick fix has been increased to 1TB.

Comment: Try running 
    dbcc loginfo (<dbname>)

How many rows do you get back? how many of those rows have a Status of 0? This will tell you how much of your t-log SQL Server thinks is still in use

Comment: 22 of 4622 rows. Dbcc opentran shows no active translations.

Answer (score 2):

run this query on your server

```
SELECT [NAME], 
       RECOVERY_MODEL_DESC,
       LOG_REUSE_WAIT_DESC,
       IS_PUBLISHED,
       IS_MERGE_PUBLISHED,
       is_subscribed
FROM SYS.DATABASES
```

[image]

if you have something different than NOTHING in the LOG_REUSE_WAIT_DESC there is where I would start investigating.

[There are eight reasons SQL Server might report when it cannot truncate the transaction log](http://sqlity.net/en/1830/log-reuse-waits-explained-log_backup/)

That is probably what is preventing the space within the log to be re-used.

For **ACTIVE_TRANSACTION**

I like to use the stored procedure called [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) it will tell you what is currently running on your server.

or much simpler, just to see if there are open transactions:

```
DBCC opentran WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

For **LOG_BACKUP**

[Why is log_reuse_wait_desc saying LOG_BACKUP after doing a log backup?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-is-log_reuse_wait_desc-saying-log_backup-after-doing-a-log-backup/)

> LOG_BACKUP really means “either you need to take a log backup, or the
>   log records that were backed up were all in the current VLF and so it
>   could not be cleared.”

[There are eight reasons SQL Server might report when it cannot truncate the transaction log](http://sqlity.net/en/1830/log-reuse-waits-explained-log_backup/)

> If your database recovery model is "full" SQL Server cannot reuse
>   virtual log files unless all contained transaction log records have
>   been backed up with a log backup. If a log backup is outstanding the
>   log has to grow to accommodate new data changes. During this time you
>   will see a log_reuse_wait_desc of LOG_BACKUP. Full or differential
>   backups do not backup all transaction log records, so you need to run
>   an actual log backup to allow for virtual log file reuse.

In this situation transaction log backups every minute I think it too high.

Find the number of VLFs in the transaction log.

I had this situation:
MY_DB (232 Gb) = 500,000 VLFs

and this is what I did (keeping each VLF = 8GB):

```
dbcc sqlperf(logspace)
go
use my_db
Go
select size/128,* from sys.sysfiles
dbcc loginfo('my_db')

-- updated my_db autogrowth to 4096Mb (chunk of 4 Gb)
DBCC SHRINKFILE(my_db_log, 1)
select size/128,* from sys.sysfiles


ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 8GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 16GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 24GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 32GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 40GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 48GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 56GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 64GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 72GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 80GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 96GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 104GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 112GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 120GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 128GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 136GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 144GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 152GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 160GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 168GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 176GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 184GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 192GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 200GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 208GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 216GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 224GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 232GB )
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'my_db_log', SIZE = 240GB )
```

[Transaction Log VLCs - each is a multiple of 4GB](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/bug-log-file-growth-broken-for-multiples-of-4gb/)

Comment: It is set to LOG_BACKUP

Answer (score 1):

So at a quick glance I looked at the backup jobs and they were successful when that really wasn't the case. Looking at the logs there were no new ones being generated. Turns out there was extra backups being kept when there shouldn't have been which took up the space on the volume where logs were stored.